# Crafting XML Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

When I am trying to save xml to a xml field in database I not getting the correct formatting I am wanting. Instead of a tag such as.

```
  <ClassDetails>
        <name>Priority</name>
        <displayName>Priority</displayName>
        <parent>Trouble Ticket</parent>
        <type>System.Int32</type>
        <length>256</length>
        <key>false</key>
        <required>false</required>
      </ClassDetails>
```

Its producing the following what is my best method for replicating the above.

```
<TextBox Name="test" Type="System.String" displayName="Test Control" />
```

//This is the code I am passing the for Update Method

```
   XElement formItem = new XElement("TextBox", new XAttribute("Name", "test"),
                  new XAttribute("Type", "System.String"),
                    new XAttribute("displayName", "Test Control"));


  portalContext.UpdateFormBuilder("Test", "form Builder" ,formItem);
```

//UpdateFormBuilder is

```
 public bool UpdateFormBuilder(string formName, string Title, System.Xml.Linq.XElement ExtraFields)

     var q = from forms in portalEntities.FormBuilders
                    where forms.Name == formName                        
                    select forms;


            List<FormBuilder> formBuilderRecords = q.ToList();
            foreach (FormBuilder formsBuilder in formBuilderRecords)
            {
                formsBuilder.Name = formName;
                formsBuilder.ExtraFields = ExtraFields.ToString();
                formsBuilder.title = Title;


            }


            return SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `XAttribute()`s in your attempted code with `XElement()`s because you want values as xml elements instead of attributes, for example :

```
XElement formItem = new XElement("ClassDetails", 
                                    new XElement("name", "Priority"),
                                    new XElement("displayName", "Priority"),
                                    new XElement("type", "System.Int32"),
                                    ......
                                    ......
                                    //do the same way for all elements
                                 );
```